# 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use yield mechanizmi in C#:

```
public void ScanLoop( OnScanStatus statusCallback, int graphId = -1 ) {
    foreach ( int it in _scanLoop( statusCallback, graphId ) ) {
    }
}

public IEnumerator _scanLoop( OnScanStatus statusCallback, int graphId ) {
    ...
    }
```

The error i get during the compilation is:

> Error 23  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerator' because
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerator' does not contain a public definition
>   for 'GetEnumerator'

can anyone tell my why? it seems strange from what i can see `IEnumerable` is the interface containing GetEnumerator

Comment: _`IEnumerable`_ is the interface containing `GetEnumerator`. That method returns an instance of `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 7):

`GetEnumerator` *returns* an `IEnumerator`, but it's a method on `IEnumerable`.

`foreach` requires an `IEnumerable`, and will get the `IEnumerator` internally. Most of the time (e.g. using `foreach` or LINQ) you will never need to handle the `IEnumerator` yourself, unless for some reason you were trying to implement your own iterable collection type.

Comment: I would add that `foreach` calls GetEnumerator to get the `IEnumerator` to use. The problem here is how `foreach` works.